# jQuery colorpicker not working as per requirement

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, color-picker

Hi friends I am facing some issues while working on `jQuery Colorpicker` tool. It's working fine but as per my requirements I don't want to open color pallete when user clicks on `altField's` and also want want when user click on `altField` the opened `color-pallet` get close. I am adding all the files included into head section please tell me when to modify in these files to achieve the goal

**Head section**

```
<script src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="script/jquery.colorpicker.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="name">
                            <input type="hidden" class="cp-basic-name" value="000000"/>
                            <img src="images/colou-pallet.png"  id="cp-hidden-input-open-name" alt="" />
                            <script>
                                        $(function() {
                                                var dialogHidden = $('.cp-basic-name').colorpicker({
                                                altField: '.col,foc',
                                                altProperties: 'color',
                                                altAlpha: true,
                                                alpha: true
                                            });
                                            $('#cp-hidden-input-open-name').click(function(e) {                                         
                                                e.stopPropagation();
                                                dialogHidden.colorpicker('open');
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                            </div>
```

Please help me guys

Thanks in advance  ...:)

Comment: how can I call all the files into jsFiddle ?

Comment: what jquery colorpicker library are you using?

Comment: @Kamal can't tell what are you using. run a sample on jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co You can include your files there